# Discord.py Detect message in Embed Title or Description

Tags: python, discord.py

I am currently trying to make an 'Anti Selfbot' Bot. I would like to do something good for the Discord Community. Therefore, I have tried to make an `on_message` event that can detect if an `Embed` contains 'selfbot', which would cause the message to get deleted and for the user to be banned.

I have already begun making my bot. However, I am not sure how to read the content of an Embed.

```py
if 'selfbot' in message.content:
    # do some stuff here
```

So, basically, the only problem I am having at the moment would be reading the embed title or description content.

Comment: I believe what you are looking for is to see if a user sent an embed. Only bots are able to send embeds unless you are using some type of hacked/modified client (Which is still against discord's TOS). So if a user has sent an embed, they would get banned. You also need to check and make sure the user isn't a bot (An actual bot not a selfbot) Or else you might end up banning your trusty dank memer.

Comment: Just to clarify, how will finding "selfbot" in someone's message verify that they are selfbotting? Are you trying to find out if a user account sent an embed?

Comment: I don't think anyone would put "selfbot" in their embed when they are selfbotting

Answer (score 1):

The below checks the title, description, footer, and fields of the embeds in a message for some text

```
from discord import Embed

def message_contains(message, text):
    return text in message.content or any(embed_contains(embed, text) for embed in message.embeds)

def embed_contains(embed, text):
    return (text in embed.title 
         or text in embed.description
         or (embed.footer.text and text in embed.footer.text) 
         or (any(text in field.name or text in field.value for field in embed.fields))
         )
```

Comment: This is nice and a great answer, but I believe `embed.footer` evaluates to `{}` if nonexistent, and `embed.footer.text` evaluates to `Embed.Empty`. So `embed.footer is Embed.Empty` will always be False.  The docs aren't very clear about this behavior. It's the same behavior for fields too, except no fields evaluate to an empty list `[]` instead of an empty dict. For example: 
`if embed.footer != {} and embed.footer.text is not discord.Embed.Empty and text in embed.footer.text: return True`

Comment: @Break The documentation seems to indicate that [`Embed.footer`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Embed.footer) has type `Union[EmbedProxy, Empty]`, that's what I was basing this on.  I would be surprised to see a pure `dict` in there.  Maybe the string repr of `EmbedProxy` or `Empty` is `{}`?

Comment: If we look at the code here for `set_footer`: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/d30fea5b0dcba9cd130026b56ec01e78bd788aff/discord/embeds.py#L345 we can see that the `self._footer` attribute itself is an empty dict, and its attributes are the ones with `Embed.Empty`. I struggled with this particular embed behavior for a while and couldn't use `Embed.Empty` properly until I realized that it's meant to be used for things like `footer.text` but not `footer` itself. I suppose the empty `{}` doesn't matter too much since we can just do `if embed.footer` instead of `if embed.footer != {}`

Comment: The docs and even the source code comments seem a little misleading about this behavior. I'd just say to try it out yourself to verify

Comment: Just wanted to come back and say that you were right about it not being `{}`, but it is also never `Embed.Empty`, so the check would instead be `if embed.footer and embed.footer.text is not discord.Embed.Empty`. The `repr` of an empty `EmbedProxy` is also `'EmbedProxy()'` so another silly but accurate check could be `if repr(embed.footer) != 'EmbedProxy()'`. For empty checks: `if repr(embed.footer) == 'EmbedProxy()'`, `if not embed.footer`, `if len(embed.footer) == 0`